# Get Group of Numbers on a String

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a string which consists of numbers and letters like the example below:

```
string strFood = "123d 4hello12";
```

What I want to accomplish is get all the group of numbers which is 123, 4, and 12.

I am trying to do this via LinQ but I am not getting the array results since my plan is to get the array then add them altogether which is 123 + 4 + 12 and the result is 139.

This is what I tried so far but this doesn't result to group of string or integer:

```
string[] strArr =
            strFood .GroupBy(y => Char.IsDigit(y)).Select(y => y.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I also tried this one but this returns all the number in one string:

```
var foo = from a in strFood .ToCharArray() where Char.IsDigit(a) == true select a;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions* to find all groups (matches) with aggregation via *Linq*:

```
string strFood = "123d 4hello12";

var sum = Regex
  .Matches(strFood, "[0-9]+") // groups of integer numbers
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value)) // treat each group as integer
  .Sum(); // sum up
```

If you want to obtain an *array* (and sum up later):

```
int[] result = Regex
  .Matches(strFood, "[0-9]+") // groups of integer numbers
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
  .ToArray();

...

var sum = result.Sum();
```

Comment: nice solution with .OfType<Match>()

Answer (score 1):

You could split your string to integers collection:

```
string  strFood = "123d 4hello12";

var integers = new Regex(@"\D").Split(strFood)
                .Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Select(x=>int.Parse(x));
```

and after that sum it with:

```
var sum = integers.Sum();  // Result : 139
```

**Edit** after comment of @Dmitry Bychenko:  with some characters, such as persian digits that won't work. 
Solution: either use

```
new Regex(@"[^0-9+]")
```

or

```
new Regex(@"\D", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
```

Comment: There's a weird counter example: `string strFood = "۱۲۳۴"` (Persian digits are used). However, I doubt if actual data can contain such characters.

Comment: ...`new Regex(@"\D", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)...` (to solve *Persian*, *Indian* and alike digits)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add decimal numbers in summation, you can use this regex instead:

```
var str = "123d 4hello12and0.2plus.1and-1and2+8.but 1....1 a.b";
//         ^^^  ^     ^^   ^^^    ^^   ^^   ^ ^     ^   ^^

var s = Regex
    .Matches(str, @"-?([0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Sum(c=> double.Parse(c.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

---

Result will be:

```
Count = 11
[0]: {123}
[1]: {4}
[2]: {12}
[3]: {0}
[4]: {.2}
[5]: {.1}
[6]: {-1}
[7]: {2}
[8]: {8}
[9]: {1}
[10]: {.1}
Sum = 149.39999999999998 //~= 149.4
```

Comment: Pattern for `double` (even if without exponential part) should be more *complex*; otherwise there'll be  counter examples: `"1...2"`, `"a.b"` etc.

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` when it's withing brackets: `[0-9.]` (but sure you can do)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks, I updated my answer for more flexibility ;).

Comment: Since you use `.` as a decimal separator, `double.Parse(c.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will be *safier* choice (what if I run your code at my workstartion with default *Russian Culture* which uses `,` as a *decimal* separator and `.` as a thousand one, so `1.2` will be treated as `12` since thousand separator will be ignored)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you again, I didn't notice that ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourSum = strFood.Where(x=>Char.IsDigit(x)).Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)).Sum()
```

This will give you the sum of all numbers in your string.

If you want just an IEnumerable of ints remove the `Sum()` from the end

Comment: @devRicher "since my plan is to get the array then add them altogether"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] strArr = strFood.ToCharArray().Where(x=> Char.IsDigit(x)).Select(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'char.IsDigit(char)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: I hope you can try this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple regular expression?

```
string input = "123d 4hello12";
int sum = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>().Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using an approach using `Split` and `Join`.

First i use Linq `Select` to replace non digits with a ',':

```
strFood.Select(ch => (Char.IsDigit(ch)) ? ch : ',');
```

I then use `Join` to turn this back into a string of the form "123,,4,,,,,12", I then `Split` this on "," and filter out values (using `Where`) which have an empty string, I then convert the string into a number e.g. "123" becomes 123 and I sum the array.

Putting this all together becomes:

```
var Sum = String.Join("",(strFood.Select(c => (Char.IsDigit(c)) ? c : ',')))
                 .Split(',').Where(c => c != "").Select(c => int.Parse(c)).Sum();
```

Here's a slightly shorter version using Concat:

```
var Sum = String.Concat(strFood.Select(ch => (Char.IsDigit(ch)) ? ch : ','))
                .Split(',').Where(c => c != "").Select(c => int.Parse(c)).Sum();
```

This gives a result of 139